# Good, elegant and secure way to pre load data for an android app

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an android app in wich I need some "static configuration" data to be preloaded and not editable. This data is also relational. And probably will change in time while the app grows in functionality.

Looking around I've seen suggestions to prepare your sqlite3 db file beforehand and then place it codewise in your typical db dir (/data/data/whateverapp/databases/preloaded.db).
But with this method I fear someone with root privileges (i.e. rooted phone) might enter and edit the data. And having to encrypt/decrypt the db file might get cumbersome and a mess (there's no native method to achieve this afaik).

I've even seen suggestions to  build classes with lists of static data. Which might work, but is somewhat messy too and not elegant.

So, Which would be a correct, elegant and secure way to achieve this?

Comment: Ah, the secure question.  Comes up a least once a day!  Short answer, you can't.  Best you can do with data on the device is encrypt then obsfucate the life out of your private key/hash/salt/algorithm.  If I have root (and I always do) then the only question is "is the cost of cracking it worth the reward"?  Plenty of discussions here on SO about how to do this.  PS.  There is no difference between SQLite and embedded static data as far as security goes.  Both just as easy, or hard to get at, depending on how many hoops you make me jump through.

Comment: I meant plenty of discussions about how to obsfucate, not how to crack ;)

Comment: I though so about the "security" part of the question. It seems it comes down to encrypt it yourself. But as you say is probably not worth the effort, if you modify the db, at least in the case of my app, it will just stop working correctly for yourself. I'm more interested in the good and elegance part though. Maybe there's something in the api to achieve this pre loading... correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of way to do this:

- bundle as resource in the app, extract and update DB, etc. on first run
- download from server, use GCM to notify about data updates. No need to update whole app when data changes
- Use Google Play expansion (or was it extension?) files. Data gets downloaded from Google Servers, your apps needs to authenticate. You need to push new app version to update data.
- Use a remote API, and forget about handling the raw data

Elegance is subjective, take your pick.

Answer (score 1):

You could just have a configuration file with defined XML resources. I've done this and it works quite well. This way if you have multiple configurations, you can backup these configuration files to work with older versions. As far as I know, I don't think you can edit these resources programatically either.

Here's a simple example of how I'm using it. 
Ie:

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="blah.blah"
      android:versionCode="@integer/version_code"
      android:versionName="@string/build_version">
```

My resources file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="version_code">1</integer>
    <string name="build_version">1.0</string>
        <string name="param">Some other Param</string>
</resources>
```

Now your program will be able to get the resources at runtime for the version code and version name. To get the other values in programmatically you can use the following code:

```
public class Configuration {
Context thisContext;
private String Param = "";

    public Configuration(Context cont){
        thisContext = cont;
        String param= thisContext.getResources().getString(R.string.param);

        setParam(param);
    }

    /**
     * @return the param
     */
    public static String getParam() {
        return Param;
    }
    /**
     * set the Param
     */
    public static void setParam(String param) {
        Param= param;
    }
}
```

Then you can just create a configuration object in your applications onCreate as so:

```
new Configuration(this);
```

Then afterwards you can use the function

```
Configuration.getParam();
```

in any class you want to get the value.

You will have to still write in the various parameters, but it is very simple to do. And if

you need to reference old versions it's as simple as swapping out the configuration file.

Hopefully this helps you!
Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was aware of the use of resource files. I have used them as well quite a lot. Is very good for some values and for labels and messages, specially for internationalization/localization purposes. But I meant data that is a little bit more complex (entities, with fields and relations...) A (very) simple example would be... imagine a quiz app in wich you want to have pre loaded the questions, question types, answer types, field types,... each with its fields and relations.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use Server based database and use strict security to let the user access the server. If you securely encrypt and obfuscate your access code and protect the user credentials, you have fended off a good deal of unexperienced hackers and would not have to worry about rooted phones because the DB is not even on the phone. As mentioned in the comments, hackers have become very clever, but this should not prevent you from making their life harder cracking your code.